# Robotium test case not Running at all

Tags: robotium

Am a day old to Robotium. Hence trying to run some apps on Robotium.

I have done a simple calci app and am trying to run it using Robotium.
But the Robotium app is not responding at all. Neither the tests are being done.

I have included the permissions in Manifest file and all. But still the Program never runs.

My Source Code for Robotium Test is like this:

```
package com.example.demo.project.test;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.demo.project.MainActivity;
import com.example.demo.project.R;
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;

public class SampleQA extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
    public SampleQA(Class<MainActivity> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    private Solo solo;

    /*public TestMain() 
    {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    public void testDisplayBlackBox() {

        //Enter 10 in first edit-field
        solo.enterText(0, "10");

        //Enter 20 in first edit-field
        solo.enterText(1, "20");

        //Click on Multiply button
        solo.clickOnButton("Multiply");

        //Verify that resultant of 10 x 20 
        assertTrue(solo.searchText("200"));

        }

    public void testDisplayWhiteBox() {

        //Defining our own values to multiply
        float firstNumber = 10;
        float secondNumber = 20;
        float resutl = firstNumber * secondNumber ;

        //Access First value (edit-filed) and putting firstNumber value in it
        EditText FirsteditText = (EditText) solo.getView(R.id.EditText01);
        solo.enterText(FirsteditText, String.valueOf(firstNumber));

        //Access Second value (edit-filed) and putting SecondNumber value in it
        EditText SecondeditText = (EditText) solo.getView(R.id.EditText02);
        solo.enterText(SecondeditText, String.valueOf(secondNumber));

        //Click on Multiply button
        solo.clickOnButton("Multiply");

        assertTrue(solo.searchText(String.valueOf(resutl)));                
        TextView outputField = (TextView) solo.getView(R.id.TextView01);        
        //Assert to verify result with visible value
        assertEquals(String.valueOf(resutl), outputField.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception{

        try {
            solo.finalize();
            } 
           catch (Throwable e) 
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            getActivity().finish();
            super.tearDown();
            }
}
```

The Test is not getting executed at all.
Please help me out Folks!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you be more specific on the errors that you are encounter? maybe put some examples?

Your main activity of the application under test it is named MainActivity?

Maybe you should change the constructor from

```
public SampleQA(Class<MainActivity> activityClass) {
    super(activityClass);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

to

```
public SampleQA() {
    super(MainActivity.class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But why does this make a difference?